# Qt5 (C++) conversion from GMT/UTC string to UNIX timestamp

Tags: c++, qt, timestamp, qdatetime

I am trying to convert from a GMT/UTC string like this:

```
11 Sep 2014 14:31:50 GMT
```

to UNIX timestamp in Qt (c++).

Here's the code (note that I have removed " GMT" from the first string):

```
QString l_time = "11 Sep 2014 14:31:50";
QDateTime l_dt = QDateTime::fromString(p_gmt_date, "dd MMM yyyy hh:mm:ss");
uint l_timestamp = l_dt.toTimeSpec(Qt::UTC).toTime_t();
```

This gives me the result:

```
l_timestamp = 1410438710
```

Of course this is wrong and I think it is due to "local" settings (consider I am in Italy).

Verifying on [this website](http://www.onlineconversion.com/unix_time.htm) I get the correct result:

```
1410445910
```

In the same website I can crosscheck that the first result is wrong since it returns:

```
Thu, 11 Sep 2014 12:31:50 GMT
```

Does anyone can help me?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed!

```
QString l_time = "11 Sep 2014 14:31:50";
QDateTime l_dt = QLocale(QLocale::Italian, QLocale::Italy).toDateTime(l_time, "dd MMM yyyy hh:mm:ss");
l_dt.setTimeSpec(Qt::UTC);
uint l_timestamp = l_dt.toTime_t();
```

This gives me the correct result:

```
1410445910
```